# Html/Angular toggle table rows to show hidden a table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am completely new to angular, I need to create a table. The data array is as-follows:-

```
data = [{rollno: 1,name: 'abc',subject: 'maths'},
        {rollno: 4,name: 'xyz',subject: 'history'},
        {rollno: 2,name: 'pqr',subject: 'history'}
       ];
```

I want to create a table with some summary rows based on this data and then when I click the expand button the sub-rows should appear beneath that summary-row indicating the actual data.

For example:-

```
Expand/Collapse | No of Students | Subject
 click here        1                Maths
 click here        2               History
```

When I toggle the expand/collapse button on the second row for example I want actual rows to appear like this beneath it:-

```
 Expand/Collapse | No of Students | Subject
 click here        1                Maths
 click here        2               History
 RollNo | StudentName
   4       xyz
   2       pqr
```

How Can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Grouping the data by subject**

First you need to group the data by `subject` and then count the items in each group.

You can use the **angular.filter** module's [**groupBy**](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby) filter to do this.

**1a)** Add a dependency on that module as follows:

```
var app = angular.module("yourModuleName", ["angular.filter"]);
```

**1b)** You can then use the `groupBy` filter in an `ng-repeat` directive on a `<tbody>` tag like this:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="(key, value) in data | groupBy: 'subject'">
```

**1c)** You're now dealing with the data in the format below. This is an object of `key`/`value` pairs where `"maths"` and `"history"` are both `keys`, and the arrays are the `values`

```
{
  "maths": [
    {
      "rollno": 1,
      "name": "abc",
      "subject": "maths",
    }
  ],
  "history": [
    {
      "rollno": 4,
      "name": "xyz",
      "subject": "history",
    },
    {
      "rollno": 2,
      "name": "pqr",
      "subject": "history",
    }
  ]
}
```

**2) Displaying the grouped data and counting the items in each group**

Use `key` and `value` to display the grouped data in a table as follows:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Subject</th>
      <th>Number of Students</th>
      <th>Expand/Collapse</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-repeat="(key, value) in data | groupBy: 'subject'">
    <tr>
      <td>{{ key }}</td>
      <td>{{ value.length }}</td>
      <td>
        <button>
          Expand/Collapse
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Roll Number</th>
              <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="student in value">
              <td>{{ student.rollno }}</td>
              <td>{{ student.name }}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note the extra `<tr>` and nested table with another `ng-repeat` for displaying the student data. Currently all nested student data will display, the next step is to conditionally show/hide the nested tables based on which expand/collapse button was clicked.

**3) Showing/Hiding the nested student data**

**3a)** Add an `ng-click` directive on the button so that it passes in the `key` to an `onExpandClicked` function on your controller:

```
<button ng-click="onExpandClicked(key)">
  Expand/Collapse
</button>
```

**3b)** Create the `onExpandClicked` function in your controller:

```
$scope.onExpandClicked = function(name){
  $scope.expanded = ($scope.expanded !== name) ? name : "";
}
```

This sets a value on the `$scope` that can be used in the view to decide whether to show/hide a section of student data. The `key` is passed into the function as the `name` parameter and `$scope.expanded` will either be set to `name` or reset to `""` depending on whether the passed in `name` is the same as the current `$scope.expanded` value or not.

**3c)** Finally, use the `$scope.expanded` variable in an `ng-if` directive on the second `<tr>` tag of `<tbody>` to show or hide the nested student data:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <!-- Omitted for brevity -->
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-repeat="(key, value) in data | groupBy: 'subject'">
    <tr>
      <!-- Omitted for brevity -->
    </tr>
    <tr ng-if="expanded === key">
      <!-- 
        Omitted for brevity 
      -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Demo**

[CodePen: How to show/hide grouped data created by the angular.filter module's groupBy filter](https://codepen.io/mjcwly/pen/PJqegy)

Answer (score 0):

Design a table with html and iterate through your `data` object with ng-repeat loop to display the data.

[ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

W3Schools has some basic examples on how to display tables with AngularJS

[Angular Tables](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_tables.asp)

Answer (score 0):

First you should replace the actual table by a div structure, because it is not possible to mix two kinds of table like you are planning (when I get you right).

You could toggle every row with a ng-click with the corresponding expanded content like this (pseudo code, I hope the idea gets clear):

```
<div class="row-header">
  <span>RollNo</span>
  <span>StudentName</span>
</div>

<div class="row-content" ng-if="!row_4_expanded" ng-click="row_4_expanded = !row_4_expanded">
  <span>4</span>
  <span>xyz</span>
</div>

<div ng-if="row_4_expanded">
  <div class="row-expanded-header">
    <span>No of Students</span>
    <span>Subject</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row-expanded-content">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>Math</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row-expanded-content">
    <span>2</span>
    <span>History</span>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row-content" ng-if="!row_2_expanded" ng-if="row_2_expanded" ng-click="row_2_expanded = !row_2_expanded">
  <span>2</span>
  <span>pqr</span>
</div>

<div ng-if="row_2_expanded">
  <div class="row-expanded-header">
    <span>No of Students</span>
    <span>Subject</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row-expanded-content">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>Math</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row-expanded-content">
    <span>2</span>
    <span>History</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

When you now click on a row, it toggle presens with the corresponding expanded one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example which resolves your problem.

```js
var indexCtrl = ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.num = 0;
  $scope.test = [{rollno: 1,name: 'abc',subject: 'maths'},
        {rollno: 4,name: 'xyz',subject: 'history'},
        {rollno: 2,name: 'pqr',subject: 'history'}
       ];
  $scope.changeShow = function(index){
    $scope.num = index;
  };
}];
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller='indexCtrl'>
<table>
  <tr>
  <td>Expand/Collapse</td>
  <td>No of Students</td>
  <td>Subject</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat='i in test' ng-class="num == $index ? red : none">{{}}
    <td ng-click='changeShow($index)'><a href="javascript:void(0)">click here</a></td>
    <td>{{$index +1}}</td>
    <td >{{i.subject}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td>RollNo</td>
  <td>StudentName</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat='i in test'>
    <td ng-show='num == $index'>{{i.rollno}}</td>
     <td ng-show='num == $index'>{{i.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  <style>
   table tr td{
        border: 1px solid black
    }
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps you.